# Publishing Applications/Glasswares which are developed with GDK

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api, google-gdk

How can we publish/distribute applications which are developed for Glass with `GDK`?

At [submission form](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/form) I don't see any `APK` file upload option. But I see a yes/no question(*Does this Glassware use invocation voice commands?*) which is a meaningful question for apps that are developed with GDK.

Am I missing something?

I just think that [submission form](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/form) is only for mirror api glasswares. Is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google has not yet announced how you can distribute GDK Glassware on MyGlass. For now, hang tight.

The submission form you link is indeed only for Mirror API Glassware. More details about distributing GDK Glassware will be announced some time after the GDK graduates from its sneak peek release level into something more stable.

Answer (score 0):

There are however multiple glass app sites. Here are 2 that I know of:

www.glass-apps.org

www.glassappz.com