# How does the user launches an app on Google Glass with Mirror API

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api, mirror

I'm trying to make a sample app on Google Glass. Currently, I do not have a device.

My question: after I finish creating the app, what is the action needed to see it on the launch page? Do I need to send an API request to add the card to the user's timeline? or I can perform some kind of a normal install, and see it on the main menu then?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of Glasswares (Glass applications):

1. GDK Glassware
2. MirrorApi Glassware

You can only distribute Mirror Api Glassware for now. [See my question and answer for it.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20338742/publishing-applications-glasswares-which-are-developed-with-gdk)

If you are trying to distribute a Mirror Api Glassware (after you finished development), you have to fill the [submission form](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/form).

Your glassware is going to be reviewed by Google. After Google approves, your Glassware is going to be seen at [MyGlass site](https://glass.google.com/myglass). Then users can go to [MyGlass site](https://glass.google.com/myglass) and register to your Glassware with OAuth flow.

Also see this [distribute page](https://developers.google.com/glass/distribute/index).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood by "launch page" you mean MyGlass page (https://glass.google.com/myglass).

If that's the case - Your Mirror-based application will appear on the user's MyGlass page  once he/she authorizes it (OAuth will be completed).

Hope this will help.